# cannot resolve method "xxx"

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have 2 spinner and 1 button. If the button is clicked, it will save the two selected item from spinner to SQLite. But I get cannot resolve method "insertTimeSheet" message.

I need help. Thanks.

**MyDatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.project.project.database;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Company.db";
    public final static String TABLE_NAME="TimeSheet";
    public static final String ID="id";
    public static final String Name="name";
    public static final String Weather="weather";
    public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TIME_SHEET="create table"+TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ Name+"TEXT,"+ Weather+"TEXT)";
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TIME_SHEET);
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(MyDatabaseHelper.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version"+oldVersion+"to"+newVersion+",which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("Drop TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }
}
```

**TimeSheetAPI.java**

```
package com.example.project.project.API;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.example.project.project.database.MyDatabaseHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class TimeSheetAPI {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private MyDatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    public String[] allColumns={MyDatabaseHelper.ID,MyDatabaseHelper.Name,MyDatabaseHelper.Weather};

    public TimeSheetAPI(Context context)
    {
        dbHelper=new MyDatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }
public long insertTimeSheet(String name,String weather)
{
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
   // values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.ID,id);
    values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Name,name);
    values.put(MyDatabaseHelper.Weather,weather);
    return database.insert(MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
}

}
```

**TimeSheet.java**

```
 public void add()
    {
        btnSaved.setOnClickListener
                (
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    long isInserted= dbHelper.insertTimeSheet(spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString(), // cannot resolve...inserttimeSheet
spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());



                }
            }
                );
        }
```

Comment: This `public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TIME_SHEET="create table"+TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+ Name+"TEXT,"+ Weather+"TEXT)";
` is **wrong**: you miss a bunch of spaces!!

Comment: Method is inside `TimeSheetAPI` class but trying to access it using `MyDatabaseHelper` class object :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `TimeSheetAPI class Object` then

```
TimeSheetAPI timesheet=new TimeSheetAPI(context);
```

then access like

```
timesheet.insertTimeSheet(.....)
```

Also refer `@Frank N. Stein` comment too

Comment: Ok, done! I gained one more vote (it seems that when some post you voted is closed, you re-gain the ability to vote!)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Thanx FNS.